# How to change marker shape and color under for loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have set of data like this

```
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y=[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25,]
```

I want to do scatter plot with

- first 5 elements of `x` and `y` with one marker shape and  increasing color from blue to red
- next 5 elements of `x` and `y` with next marker and color same as in the first one.

In fact I have `x` with 1000 elements and `y` with 10x100 elements. I want to plot (10 set of   scatter points) 10 different marker shape and all starting color from blue to red.

Example:

```
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y=[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25,]
c=['o', '*']
z=[.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, .99]
plt.scatter( X, Y, marker=x, c=z)
```

Comment: Scatter currently does not broadcast over markers.  If you want N different marker shapes, then you need to write a loop and call `scatter` N times.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you have some issues in your code, the variables are uppercase and then lowercase, but Python is case sensitive.

The `marker` option just allow a single character, so you can't pass a list of them. Instead, you need to loop and change for every piece that you want. A small example with your data is below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y=[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25,]
marker= ['o', 's']
z=[.1, .3, .5, .7, .99]

n = 5
for k in range(2):    
    plt.scatter(x[k*n:(k + 1)*n], y[k*n:(k + 1)*n], s=100,
                  marker=marker[k], c=z)
```

This gives as result
[image]